# D3 - Make sure size of bar width is consistent

Tags: css, d3.js, svg

I am new to D3 and working through bar chart example. What I am trying to make sure that the height of the bars and labels are consistent. Right now it is dependent on the number of entries coming back. So if there is 1, there is one giant blob. If there is 10 then the bars are slower. Here is the code and a link.

https://plnkr.co/edit/CZEyIaOxItoWZXSQkqjH?p=preview

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
body {
  margin: 15px;
  background-color: #F1F3F3    
}
.bar {
    fill: #6F257F;
}
.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #D4D8DA;
  stroke-width: 1px;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.x path {
    display: none;
}
.toolTip {
    position: absolute;
  display: none;
  min-width: 80px;
  height: auto;
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #6F257F;
  padding: 14px;
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 80},
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div").attr("class", "toolTip");

var x = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scaleBand().range([height, 0]);

var g = svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.json("data.json", function(error, data) {
    if (error) throw error;

    data.sort(function(a, b) { return a.value - b.value; });

    x.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);
    y.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.area; })).padding(0.1);

    g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(5).tickFormat(function(d) { return parseInt(d / 1000); }).tickSizeInner([-height]));

    g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

    g.selectAll(".bar")
        .data(data)
      .enter().append("rect")
        .attr("class", "bar")
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("height", y.bandwidth())
        .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.area); })
        .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.value); })
        .on("mousemove", function(d){
            tooltip
              .style("left", d3.event.pageX - 50 + "px")
              .style("top", d3.event.pageY - 70 + "px")
              .style("display", "inline-block")
              .html((d.area) + "<br>" + "£" + (d.value));
        })
            .on("mouseout", function(d){ tooltip.style("display", "none");});
});
</script>
```

data.json

```
[
    {"area": "central ", "value": 18000},
    {"area": "Riverside ", "value": 17000},
    {"area": "Picton ", "value": 80000},
    {"area": "Everton ", "value": 55000},
    {"area": "Kensington ", "value": 100000},
    {"area": "Kirkdale", "value": 50000},
     {"area": "Evertons ", "value": 5000},
    {"area": "Kensingtons ", "value": 100000},
     {"area": "Everton ", "value": 55000},
    {"area": "Kensington ", "value": 100000},
    {"area": "Kirkdale", "value": 50000}


]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to make sure that each bar has always the same height in pixels, regardless the number of bars.

If that's correct, set the range dynamically. For instance:

```
var barSize = 40;
y.range([barSize*data.length, 0]);
```

Here is your plunker with the complete data array: https://plnkr.co/edit/zNOMcQob6fSFkEYclyzS?p=preview

Now, for comparison, the same code with just three data elements: https://plnkr.co/edit/KciR2eheLLIOS1SHUM7i?p=preview

PS: You have duplicated names for the `area` property. That doesn't work with an ordinal scale.

PPS: A good idea is also setting the SVG height according to the data length.